# how to fetch content after comma as a delimiter

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a text file a.txt with content:
```````a.txt```````````
text,sometext,/|

```
I want to find characters such as ,/\| in the section after the first comma that is sometext,/\| so I used the command:

cat a.txt | head -1 | grep 'text' | awk -F "," '{print $2}' to fetch the section after first comma. My expectation is to fetch entire text that is sometext,/\| but it is considering the second , as a delimiter and only fetching sometext. 

Please help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your inputfile have a fixed format you can use

```
grep 'text' a.txt | cut -d "," -f 2-
```

Comment: I want it to cut after first comma and fetch all the content after that. Your approach also fetches till the second comma

Comment: Updated the answer. Is this what you need? If you type `man cut` there is a description of the syntax with some basic examples.